# NOT IN Sub Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to exclude records where they are returned as part of a sub query. Return a list of all 'Items' which have a location = 'Q', a positive quantity on hand and there have been no transactions in the last 14 days. When i run the two queries separately they both work fine but when i run them together as below no records are returned although there are definitely matching records.

```
SELECT l.item AS 'Item'
    FROM itemloc l
    WHERE l.loc = 'Q' AND l.qty_on_hand > 0
    AND l.item NOT IN 
    (SELECT t.item
    FROM  transaction t
    WHERE t.RecordDate > DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY t.item)
```

Comment: I would use the `l.id` instead, since it's unique ... `where l.id not in` (provide you have a way of getting the id in here)

Comment: Is the subquery returning any nulls? That breaks NOT IN, not exists works well for those cases, or in your subquery check for t.item IS NOT NULL

Comment: Sample fiddle could help us understand your problem  a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `not in`, use `not exists` (or a `left join` and comparison to `NULL`).  So, try this:

```
WHERE l.loc = 'Q' AND l.qty_on_hand > 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM  transaction t
                  WHERE t.RecordDate > DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()) and t.item = l.item
                 )
```

The problem is (probably) that `t.item` takes on a `NULL` value.  In that case, the `NOT IN` returns "unknown" or "false".  And, "unknown" is treated as false.  So, when the subquery has a `NULL` value, the expression can never return "true".

You can also fix this by adding a `where` clause in the subquery.  However, I find that the semantics of `NOT IN` are unintuitive to just about everyone.  For that reason, I recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Also, you don't need a `group by` the subquery.  That is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

edit the `item` column, make it not nullable, this is where your correct sql query breaks. or use joins instead